# how to upload stored image in datastore in google appengine?

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an image stored as Blob in data store in google appengine (python) .. i want to upload this image to a server .

1- what is required to be done to upload this stored image to the server ?

Comment: Does the server provide some sort of API for uploading images?

Comment: i'm using python sdk for facebook graph api , i want to upload the image to some album ,, how can i deal with blob data where the API require the source of image to upload

Comment: Do whatever the Facebook graph API library expects you to do to upload images, then - this isn't specific to App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the API that you are dealing with wants to have a URL from which to fetch the image, what you can do is set up a handler that will serve the image from the blob.

The AppEngine Docs lay out [what you need to do in your code](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob). Is there something specific about those instructions that you don't understand?

Comment: i've already did , and i have a url for the image for example this is http://refacingme.appspot.com/img?img_id=agpyZWZhY2luZ21lcg8LEghGQkltYWdlcxipRgw&order=1  .. so can i upload image from this link ??

Comment: Well, when I click on that link, it shows me an image. I don't know much of anything about the Facebook API, but if Facebook is asking for a URL, why wouldn't it work for them?